# Error message: Can't start Mongo server -- How to solve?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a problem that, while researching resolutions, I've seen many people have had.
When trying to run my new Meteor application, I get the following error:

$meteor

=> Started proxy.
=> Started HMR server.
Unexpected mongo exit code 3221225785. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 3221225785. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 3221225785. Restarting.
Can't start Mongo server.

Check how to troubleshoot here
https://docs.meteor.com/windows.html#cant-start-mongo-server

The system I use is Windows 8.1. Meteor v2.3.4.
I've already found many solutions on the internet and even here. However, I did everything, but nothing worked.
I've reinstalled, installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2015, deleted folders like .meteor/local, among other things...
Help me please!
I'm starting to study and learn how to build applications in Meteor, but this is slowing me down, preventing and discouraging me to continue.
Is there any way to fix this? Will I have to forget about Meteor?
Edit:
The many people who have faced this same error have found them on other forums as well as in the comments of issues on Github, and on the Meteor forum itself. They had the same problem as me, but some of the solutions they were presented with resolved the error for them.
I've already tried:

- Remove Meteor, reinstalling it through an executable installer and then using NPM (npm install -g meteor);
- Install Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable for Windows 8.1;
- Create a new project in different folders;
- Delete files like 'mongodb.lock';
- Change DBPath from C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\data to C:\data, or C:\My-project.meteor\local\db; * Change Mongo's port to 3000 (but already back to default value: 27017);
- Add some package referring to Mongo in Meteor ($meteor add mongo);
  But absolutely nothing in the list above worked for me. The same error keeps popping up. :(.
  My MongoDB version is 4.2, the latest compatible for Windows 8.1.

Comment: doesn't seem to be many results for *exit code 3221225785* - where are these "many people" you say have had the problem? and what are these *other things* you've tried? Don't want to repeat what doesn't work! that link by the way is a different error

Comment: Also, what version of Mongo?

Comment: If you convert that exit code to hexadecimal, it is C0000139, which is "Entry point not found".

Comment: I added information that responds to the above comments to my post.